# Error al Implementar sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

Estoy intentando implementar SweetAlert2 en una appweb y después de comprobar en foros y web, no veo ningún fallo en el codigo pero no hay forma de ver el mensaje.

La página en la que lo estoy probando contiene un botón de tipo link  que elimina un registro de la base de datos. El registro lo elimina pero no aparece el mensaje de SweetAlert2

Dicha página contiene el siguiente  :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/sweetAlert.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Y en un link  que hace la vez de botón tengo el id id="btnConfirm"

```
<td><a id="btnConfirm" href="del_register.php?Del=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id_mov']); ?>&Page=<?php echo base64_encode('movimientos'); ?>" ><img src="../../../images/delete.png" alt="Borrar Registro" title="Borrar Registro"></td>
```

En el archivo jscript.js, tengo lo siguiente:

Una constante que crea el objeto con el mismo nombre que el id, el evento addEventListener que al hacer click llama a la función.

```
const $btnConfirm = document.querySelector("#btnConfirm");
$btnConfirm.addEventListener("click", mgsDelete);
function mgsDelete() {
Swal.fire({
  title: "ESTÁ ELIMINANDO UN REGISTRO",
  text: "¿Está Seguro?",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,

  confirmButtonText: "Sí, Eliminar",
  cancelButtonText: "No, Cancelar!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false,
},
function (isConfirm) {
  if (isConfirm) {
    Swal.fire("Borrado", "¡¡¡ El registro ha sido eliminado !!!");
  } else {
    Swal.fire("Cancelado", "¡¡¡ El registro NO ha sido eliminado !!!");
  }
});
}
```

Como digo no aparece el mensaje y no sé donde más mirar.

Agradecería si alguién me puede ayudar a ver donde tengo el problema.

Muchas gracias de antemano.